# Changing log level for a keyword in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am trying to change log levels programmatically for a given keyword. For example If I have the log level set to OFF but want to see logs that contain "database" keyword, how can I do that? Is there a way to to that via java?

Comment: Might be able to use some sort of [filter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/filters.html).

Comment: You may use the Log4j RegexFilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fatCop's answer is mostly correct. You can start with log4j2.xml configured as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="AppName" packages="">
  <RegexFilter regex="*database*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="DENY"/>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
             filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
          <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Because this is using a global filter it will cause nothing to be logged. When you are ready to enable logging do

```
final LoggerContext loggerContext = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
Filter filter = RegexFilter.createFilter("database", null, false, Result.ACCEPT, RESULT.DENY);
config.setFilter(filter);
```

When you want it disabled then replace the filter with a new one that is set back to DENY on a match.

Note that the logging level on the root logger is irrelevant since the filter is only accepting or denying events.

Comment: The programmatic configuration is absolutely fine. Just a small correction, to see logs containing 'database', regex String should be `"*database*"`. cool!

Answer (score 1):

As per [Log4j Filter Manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html), you can use `RegexFilter`. Snippet referring to manual, the configuration for you can be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="AppName" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
      <RegexFilter regex="*database*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way to do it via java code and not change the xml file?

Comment: Do you mean programmatic configuration of Log4j?

Comment: @MohammadEtemad https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html

Comment: I tried something like this, posted below, but no luck.